# Add up how many 'yes' answers

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have created a spreadsheet where my players mark how many players i have available for a game by selecting available or unavailable in a row for a game. How do I get a formula to automatically add up how many 'available' players i have and input that into a column further on? I feel it is a very simple thing to be able to do and maybe i am missing an option so if someone could help me out, that would be great. I have tried to find the right forumula but unable to find one that works.
Thanks

Comment: I'd highly suggest not using Excel to store data and retrieve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.